# Team foundation Service (http://<user domain>.visualstudio.com/) Pricing

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

For example I have 10 users in the system.
Can I use 20 different users in one system: 10 user in project1 and other 10 in project2?

Briefly, number of prepaid users are for one project? Or per domain?

Comment: as far I know you can have 5 users with the free version & then you have to pay as per your number of users, if you take a license for 20 users, you can employ those users to multiple projects.

Comment: Simply I couldn't find this policy described in documentation

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/Optikal/archive/2013/09/10/153981.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It’s based on domain not projects.**

Such as in https://account1.visualstudio.com, you can add the other 9 users in this domain. Then you can set permissions of the other 9 users for different projects.

More details, you can refer [visual studio licensing white paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350).